# Freezing of queue and thread

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, threadpool, python-multithreading

In the code below, the program freezes completely in the `second.put(data)` section for the url.

I thought the error was caused by the status code of the urls. (Because there was no problem on different websites.) I created a filter for this. But that didn't work.

```py
from threading import Thread
import queue
import requests

websites = [..........]

threadCount = 50
first= queue.Queue(threadCount * 2)
second= queue.Queue(threadCount * 2)

def webreader():
    while True:
        site = first.get()
        try:
            req = requests.get(site, timeout=6})
            status = req.status_code
            data = {'URL': site, 'STATUS': status}
            req.close()
            if status == 200 or status == 201 or status == 204 or status == 301 or status == 302 \
                 or status== 307 or status == 401 or status == 403 or status == 403 or status == 500:

                second.put(data) # It freezes after an average of 305 requests.
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            req.close()

        first.task_done()

def insertDatabase():
    while True:
        getData = second.get()
        ...
        ...
        second.task_done()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(threadCount):
        t = Thread(target = webreader)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    for site in websites:
        first.put(site)


    for i in range(threadCount):
        t = Thread(target = insertDatabase)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    first.join()
    second.join()
```

Comment: Suggest you change the "naked" `except:` in `webreader()` to `except Exception as exc:` and replace the `pass` below it with `print(exc)` because what it may be hiding an unexpected error (and important clue).

Comment: @martineau Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code — other than what I already mentioned — but since you haven't provided a [mre] I can't run your code and try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You use the blocking methods for the queues and you also set the upper limit so either there are no available items or free slots. You can try with block=False and see if the Empty or Full exception will be thrown.